# How to move top widget to the left - Responsive Theme WordPress

Tags: widgets

I have WordPress, responsive theme and whenever I upload a **top widget**, it stays a bit to the left from the header. How can I move the top widget to go close to the header image as in the picture?

[image]

The header image is simply an image and the top widget image is a Google content matched ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS to your theme's CSS:

```
#top-widget {
    float: left;
}
```

If that fails you may try this:

```
#top-widget {
    float: left !important;
}
```

Once you add your CSS ensure that you have cleared your cache.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.